# Weird behavior in java.text.SimpleDateFormat expecting yyyyMMdd given yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have encountered a very weird behavior while using `SimpleDateFormat` for parsing a string to a date. Consider the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void testParse() throws ParseException
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    String dateStr = "2012-12-21";
    Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(parsedDate);

    Assert.assertEquals(2012, date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    Assert.assertEquals(11, date.get(Calendar.MONTH)); // yeah, Calendar sucks
    Assert.assertEquals(21, date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

As it can be seen there is an intentional *mistake* in the above code: the `SimpleDateFormat` is initialized with `"yyyyMMdd"` but the string to be parsed is in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. I would expect that such thing results in a `ParseException`, or at least be parsed on a best-effort basis *correctly*. Instead, for some weird reason the date is parsed as `2011-11-02`. Eh?!

This is unacceptable as one single mistake while handling the inputs would result in something totally unexpected / devastating. Switched to JodaTime in the meantime, but it would be nice to understand what went wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the input would be split into 3 components: year, month, day and you'd get <strike>month = -12</strike> and <strike>day = -21</strike> (for correction see below). Try to parse `2012/12/21` and you'll get the exception :)

Edit: excerpt from the JavaDoc:

> **Month:** If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

Edit2: Correction

Looking at the source of `SimpleDateFormat` it seems that `2012-12-21` is actually split into this:

```
year = "2012"
month = "-1"
day = "2-"
```

The source comments state that a `-` following a number might either denote a negative number (depending on the locale) or be a delimiter. In your case it seems to be taken as a delimiter, thus `day = "2-"` results in `day = 2`, hence the *second* of November.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation! I still don't understand though why -12 months is November, and why -21 days is the 8th of it. I suppose that is an underflow? I don't see it described anywhere in the docs.

Comment: @Daniel Internally `SimpleDateFormat` uses `Calendar` which - as the others already suggested - by default is lenient and thus adjusts negative values that are passed in.

Comment: Thanks for solving the mystery!

Answer (score 12):

Extract from [JavaDoc for `setLenient`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29):

> `public void setLenient(boolean lenient)`
>
> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With lenient parsing, the parser  may use **heuristics** to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format.
> With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

If you set it to false, you will get `ParseException`

Comment: I nominate `lenient == true` for the best default value of 20st century award (yes, it was [present](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall97/cs461/jdkdocs/api/java.text.DateFormat.html#_top_) in Java 1.1.4, released Sep 12th 1997.). Next, I vote to add `lenient` to [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), so that it uses proper heuristics when adding (but not when removing) elements.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `DateFormat.parse()` function, the string must satisfy the input format. if it doesn't do it, the parse function parse wrong. Here a comment about this in the javaDoc:

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used
>   by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then
>   the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the
>   format by calling setLenient(false).

Then, your problem would be fixed adding the `setLenient(false)` line. In this case, Java throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call setLenient(false). The default is true and Java tries to convert the string even it does not match 100%.